# TypeError: write_form() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I am using python, and Google App engine to make a basic webpage.

The problem is with the following line

```
self.self_form("That doesn't look valid to me, friend.")
```

When I save my file and refresh the webpage. I get the following error

line 94, in post
    self.write_form("That doesn't look valid to me, friend.")
TypeError: write_form() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

```
import webapp2

form="""
<form method="post">
    When is your birthday????
    <br>
    <br>

    <label> Day
    <input type="text" name="day">
    </label>

    <label> Month
    <input type="text" name="month">
    </label>

    <label> Year
    <input type="text" name="year">
    </label>

    <div style="color: red">%(error)s </div

    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
"""

months = ['January',
          'February',
          'March',
          'April',
          'May',
          'June',
          'July',
          'August',
          'September',
          'October',
          'November',
          'December']

month_abbvs = dict((m[:3].lower(),m) for m in months)

month_abbvs = dict((m[:3].lower(), m) for m in months)

def valid_month(month):
    if month:
        short_month = month[:3].lower()
        return month_abbvs.get(short_month)

def valid_day(day):
    if day.isdigit():
        return int(day) if int(day) in range(1,32) else None
    else:
        return None

def valid_year(year):
    if year.isdigit():
        return int(year) if int(year) in range(1900, 2021) else None
    else:
        return None

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def write_form(error=""):
        self.response.out.write(form % {"error": error} )

    def get(self):
        #self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.write_form()

    def post(self):
    #self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        user_month = valid_month(self.request.get('month'))
        user_day = valid_day(self.request.get('day'))
        user_year = valid_year(self.request.get('year'))

        if not(user_day and user_year and user_month):
            self.write_form("That doesn't look valid to me, friend.")
        else:
            self.response.out.write("Thanks! That's a totally valid day!")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([ ('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

What could be the problem here?

The code comes from Udacity Web Development Course, Lesson 5, video 39

Comment: `def write_form(error=""):` should be `def write_form(self, error=""):`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be defined as `def write_form(self, error=""):`